# Why am I receiving this error? IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, html, css

Disclaimer: I'm somewhat of a noob in Python so there's that.
I'm trying to webscrape this number from a website, but I keep getting this error.

```
price = soup.find_all('div', {'id':'ember105'})[0].find('text').text  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm trying to retrieve that number `14,795`

What am I doing wrong?

Python and HTML below

```py
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://covid19.min-saude.pt/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
nCases= soup.find_all('div', {'id':'ember106'})[0].find('text').text
print('number cases = ' + str(nCases))
```

```html
<div id="ember106" class="flex-fix allow-shrink indicator-center-text responsive-text flex-vertical ember-view"><svg class="responsive-text-group" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0.0000043483596527948976 -0.16839377582073212 439.04144287109375 160.01295471191406" width="208" height="50">
  <g class="responsive-text-icon">
    <!---->
  </g>

  <g class="responsive-text-label">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 -153 529.609375 193" height="160" width="439.0544041450777">
      <text vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" style="fill: rgb(255, 170, 0); stroke-width: 2; font-size: 160px; line-height: normal;">14,795</text>
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the data you're looking for is not in the initial page load; if you check `r.text`, it doesn't contain any elements called "ember106".

On the web page, it's shown in an iframe, which itself loads it via JavaScript (possibly as JSON).

You'll either have to (a) scrape via Selenium so that all the machinery can run, or (b) trace through it by hand, figure out where the JSON data is coming from and get it there directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not finding anything.

In the below command...

```
nCases= soup.find_all('div', {'id':'ember106'})[0] ...
```

You assume that you find something in the find_all() command.  It seems as though that is not a safe assumption.  Check that the size of the results of the find_all() function is greater than 0.

You may want to do the same with the find() function that is chained after it